# Apache 2.4.6 (User mod 403)

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, usermod

Hello (Sorry for my bad english)

I have a big problem on my server (Debian)
I have do the upgrade and for all my clients (mysite.fr/~user) I have an error 403 :

In /etc/log/apache2/error.log

> [Mon Dec 23 13:56:08.295684 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 22110] [client 127.0.0.1:51723] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/st0002/www/1/

So I have do change all :

> Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all

To

> Require all granted

The most surprising is that my all site which don't use mysite.fr/~* are okay.
I have update all apache mod that i use but nothing change.

Comment: Since you figured out the solution, would you put that information into an answer here and then mark that answer as accepted?  That lets the system track solved problems in a way that it can't do if you just add "Solved" to the subject line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

In /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf (i have the file version for apache 2.2)

So i have add

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It's good have a good day